# distinct value per column

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, partition

I am looking at a report on policy exceptions based on various criteria such as Beacon Score, Debt to Income, and Loan to Value. This information is kept in multiple different tables, and right now the Loan to Value column is causing multiple entries in my report because a specific loan might have multiple pieces of collateral. For proper exception monitoring, I only need one entry.

With all that said, how might I execute the following code, with a distinct value for dbo.Folders.Id? Just putting 'DISTINCT' after the SELECT statement does not seem to work. (Sensitive values masked with '#'.)

```
SELECT  dbo.Folders.LoanOfficerId, 
        dbo.Folders.Id, 
        dbo.CollateralType.Description, 
        dbo.Customers.CUSTNAME, 
        dbo.Folders.DateLoanActivated, 
        dbo.Folders.CurrentAccountBalance, 
        dbo.Folders.UnadvancedCommitAmount, 
        dbo.Folders.BeaconScore, 
        dbo.Folders.DebtToIncome, 
        dbo.Collateral.LoanToValue
  FROM dbo.Folders 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customers 
           ON dbo.Folders.CustomersNAMEKEY = dbo.Customers.NAMEKEY 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Collateral 
           ON dbo.Folders.Id = dbo.Collateral.FoldersID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.CollateralType 
           ON dbo.Collateral.CollateralTypeCollCode = dbo.CollateralType.CollCode
  WHERE (     (dbo.Folders.BeaconScore < ###) 
          AND (dbo.Folders.BeaconScore > ###) 
          AND (dbo.Folders.CloseCode = 'O') 
          AND (dbo.Folders.CollateralCode <> ##)
        ) 
        OR (     (dbo.Folders.CloseCode = 'O') 
             AND (dbo.Folders.CustomerType <> '###') 
             AND (dbo.Folders.CustomerType <> '###') 
             AND (dbo.Folders.DebtToIncome > ##)
           ) 
        OR (     (dbo.Folders.CloseCode = 'O') 
             AND (dbo.Folders.CustomerType = '###') 
             AND (dbo.Folders.DebtToIncome > ##)
           ) 
        OR (     (dbo.Folders.CloseCode = 'O') 
             AND (dbo.Folders.CustomerType = '###') 
             AND (dbo.Folders.DebtToIncome > ##)
           )
        OR (dbo.Collateral.LoanToValue > dbo.CollateralType.LTV)
```

Any constructive criticism on my code is welcome. (Static values in the above statement are on the docket to be corrected later with a thresholds/criteria table.) From what I have seen, others have suggested using ROW_COUNT() with PARTITION, but I am unable to make the syntax work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment about formatting:  learn to use table aliases.  They make the query easier to read and write.

If you only need one row from the results, you can use `row_number()`.  This enumerates the rows for each folder (in your case) and you would just use the first one.  You can do this using:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by FoldersId order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

On the other hand, if you needed to aggregate information from the collateral tables, then you would use `group by` in your query with the appropriate aggregation functions.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon! I had seen this in earlier responses. My entire problem resided in the partition by part. The column heading in the partition by should be simply "Id." I figured this out when I tried ORDER BY dbo.Folders.DateLoanActivated and got the error. ORDER BY DateLoanActivated worked fine. Thanks again! I would upvote if I had the cred!